# Dough is super springy and sticky. Tears while stretching

Tags: pizza

I work with 950 gms of 00 flour and 50 gms of wheat gluten to make it 1000 gms. I  knead the dough at 65% hydration with 1/4 tsp Instant dry yeast  for 1000 gms of flour. 2% Salt and 4 tabsp Oil .. I knead till windowpane test and let rest for 24 hours.. but next day my dough becomes super springy and soggy. Never looks smooth. Looks like orange peel skin. I make balls and leave them to rest before I make my pizza. It tears while I’am stretching it to make thin crust pizza. What could be the problem? Am I over kneading my dough? Is my gluten content less? Please help!!!!

Comment: 1/4 tsp of yeast for 1 kg of dough sounds very little to me, are you getting any rise?

Comment: Tnks for your response GdG .Yes. Lots of it! The dough almost overflows after 24 hours.

Comment: How are you proofing this for 24 hours, on the counter or in the fridge?

Comment: 5% gluten is pretty low to expect expect your dough to stretch without tearing. I'd go 12% at least. https://www.thespruceeats.com/all-about-flour-995124

Comment: @Wayfaring stranger...tnks for your response. I add 5 % gluten all right. But my APF is 00 and already has 9.6% gluten in it.. that’s why I add 5% more only. That makes my flour more than 14% gluten. That’s Sir Lancelot flour %

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all sounds normal except the part where it tears when you stretch it. You should make sure you leave enough time for the dough balls to proof (they'll double in size) and relax before you shape them. If you have 24 hours before bake time, you don't even need to knead after mixing. Look up no knead pizza dough.

Comment: Thank you for your response.. the dough balls double in size. I think I will try the no knead method like you suggested..

Answer (score 2):

Are you resting in the fridge? 24 hours is a long time to leave a yeast dough at room temp. Try letting rise for a shorter time or in the fridge a max of 12 hours.

Comment: This isn't an answer @SqueakyBeak, it's more of a comment, one that's been made as well.

Comment: That comment was posted 2 hours after my comment and my suggestion is one I think that will solve their problem.